# Using the substitution $u=x^3$, find the general solution of $xy''+y'+9x^5=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using the substitution $u=x^3$, find the general solution of $xy''+y'+9x^5=0$.

I have no idea about above question? Could somebody suggest me a solution or resource for such problems?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$u=x^3\implies\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2$$

Using Chain Rule, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{du}$$

$$\implies x\frac{dy}{dx}=3u\cdot\frac{dy}{du}$$

Differentiating wrt $x$ $$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=3\left[\frac{du}{dx}\cdot\frac{dy}{du}+u\cdot\frac{d\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)}{dx}\right]$$

$$=3\left[3x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{du}+u\cdot\frac{d\dfrac{dy}{du}}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}\right]$$

$$\implies x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=9x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{du}+u\cdot\frac{d^2y}{du^2}\cdot3x^2$$

Then replace $x^3$ with $u$ and use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest an alternative method.

Note that $(xy')'=xy''+y'$.

Hence we have:

\begin{align}
(xy')' +9x^5 &=0 \\
(xy')' &=-9x^5 \\
xy'&= -\frac{3}{2} x^6+c_1 \\
y'&=-\frac{3}{2} x^5+\frac{c_1}{x} \\
y &=-\frac{x^6}{4}+c_1 \ln(x)+c_2
\end{align}

Comment: This method does not contain substitution.